# How to repair DCDiag Connectivity test on windows server 2012

Tags: dns, active-directory, ip, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller

We have two Domain controllers on our second domain. Both fail dcdiag connectivity test. Neither can update DNS records, AD won't start because a domain controller cannot be found and all of the certificates on this domain have expired.

When I restart the server it adds dc2001 to the dns zones, rather than dc2001.domain.local which is already there.

When I ping dc2001 I get a reply from fe80::1d61:f361:801a:bbfc%17 time<1ms.

When I ping dc2001.domain.local I get a reply from 10.93.41. with bytes=32 time<1ms TTL-128.
I'm not sure why I'm getting the ipv6 address in response rather than the ipv4 address.

I've tried registering DNS and it fails. 
I've tried disconnecting the DNS zone from AD, and then registering DNS, but it's adding in dc2001 without the FQDN and still can't resolve DNS addresses.

I've tried to add that particular host that is failing the DNS test to the correct spot in DNS. I tried both a hostname and a cname, but the DNS server doesn't seem to be responding even to its own queries.

Any help on next steps, or how to fix this connectivity issue and our domain would be greatly appreciated.

```
Here is my ipconfig /all
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : dc2001
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.local

Ethernet adapter Ethernet1 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-01-17-08
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d61:f361:801a:bbfc%17(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.93.41.1(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.93.41.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 335564886
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1B-3C-C0-C4-00-50-56-01-05-9A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.93.41.1
                                       10.93.41.3
                                       127.0.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.rwl.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Here's my dcdiag fails

```
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

   Trying to find home server...

   Home Server = dc2001

   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Done gathering initial info.


Doing initial required tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site\DC2001

      Starting test: Connectivity

         The host e9aff47f-e80d-4a27-a362-e790dd8dc3a6._msdcs.domain.local could

         not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server

         name, etc.

         Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your

         firewall settings.

         ......................... DC2001 failed test Connectivity



Doing primary tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site\DC2001

      Skipping all tests, because server DC2001 is not responding to directory

      service requests.



   Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

         ......................... DomainDnsZones passed test

         CrossRefValidation


   Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test CheckSDRefDom

      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

         ......................... ForestDnsZones passed test

         CrossRefValidation


   Running partition tests on : Schema

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation


   Running partition tests on : Configuration

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation


   Running partition tests on : rwl

      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom

         ......................... rwl passed test CheckSDRefDom

      Starting test: CrossRefValidation

         ......................... rwl passed test CrossRefValidation


   Running enterprise tests on : domain.local

      Starting test: LocatorCheck

         Warning: DcGetDcName(GC_SERVER_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355

         A Global Catalog Server could not be located - All GC's are down.

         Warning: DcGetDcName(TIME_SERVER) call failed, error 1355

         A Time Server could not be located.

         The server holding the PDC role is down.

         Warning: DcGetDcName(GOOD_TIME_SERVER_PREFERRED) call failed, error

         1355

         A Good Time Server could not be located.

         Warning: DcGetDcName(KDC_REQUIRED) call failed, error 1355

         A KDC could not be located - All the KDCs are down.

         ......................... domain.local failed test LocatorCheck

      Starting test: Intersite

         ......................... domain.local passed test Intersite
```

NSlookup returns:

```
Default Server: UnKnown
Address: 10.93.41.1
```

Comment: This would be better suited to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com) as this site is for programming related issues. Check the [help] on how to migrate it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will post server errors at serverfault in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by removing DNS zones, and then re-adding them as local zones, not AD zones. Then registering DNS. 
After that I restarted Netlogon. 
Then I rebuilt FRS and SYSVOL. 
AD finally started working, and connection errors were removed.